# Oversampling in OFDM

Tags: lowpass-filter, ofdm

Why do we need an oversampling in OFDM signal? and how to do it? 
If around half of the Sub-carriers are only used to send data, then do we need to perform oversampling to the signal? Is it necessary to have LPF in OFDM transceiver?

Comment: Could you provide some more detail about what you're asking specifically? Sampled OFDM signals require the same Nyquist criterion that any other discrete-time signal would in order to avoid aliasing. I would say that in general, though, using oversampling in OFDM systems wouldn't be typical.

Comment: I have seen some implementation of OFDM where they insert an interpolation and windowing block. I don't understand the need for this block? Is it a must to have it or I can eliminate it if I am using less number of data sub-carriers compared to IFFT size? I am new to communication field so can you please clarify to me what to do with OFDM signal after IFFT block in transmitter side if I am going to send it at IF or RF frequency.

Comment: If possible you should provide a reference to what you're asking about then so it will be easier to provide an answer.

Comment: In the book of "OFDM for Wireless Communications Systems" by Ramjee Prasad 2004. There is a block diagram where they include windowing block.

Comment: Also, in this reference they are using raised cosine function https://www.cresis.ku.edu/~rvc/documents/862/862_ofdmreport.pdf

Comment: Link for the book: http://www.upv.es/titulaciones/MUTSRC/info/U0581064.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Oversampling in OFDM is usually implemented by modulating some subcarriers at the spectrum margins with zero. This zero-padding in frequency domain corresponds to oversampling in time domain. If only 50% percent of the subcarriers are used, then this corresponds to an oversampling factor of 2. Specifically, if the total number of subcarriers is $N$ and if $M$ of these subcarriers are set to zero, then the oversampling factor is $N/(N-M)$. Note, that the $M$ zero subcarriers have to be arranged in a row, cyclic shifting allowed. Normally, they're arranged symmetrically at the lowest and highest frequencies.

An OFDM transmitter might require a low pass filter in order to keep out-of-band radiation low. The cut-off frequency is usually half of the sampling frequency ($f_\mathrm{s}$).

An OFDM receiver requires a low pass filter before A/D conversion (sampling) with cut-off frequency $f_\mathrm{s}/2$. Otherwise aliasing can occur.

Comment: So, the LPF is optional in transmitter to remove out of band radiation while its a must in the receiver to avoid aliasing? In a transmitter the LPF is placed before DAC and in receiver before ADC?

Comment: I would say the transmitter LPF is optional, yes. The filter is analogue and has to be placed after the DAC and before the ADC.

Comment: I am confused why in a transmitter the LPF is placed after the DAC? can you please clarify. In the book I referred in my previous comment in section 5.2.1, figure 5.1 they are putting windowing block before the DAC! many thanks

Comment: The LPF that I'm talking about is an analogue device that suppresses alias spectra caused by the digital-to-analog conversion. It therefore must be placed *after* the DAC. The windowing block in the figure you're referring to is for spectral shaping.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify if I got it right. In this case the windowing block is optional in the transmitter while the LPF after the DAC is a must to avoide aliasing? or the analog LPF after the DAC is also optional since we are using LPF in receiver before the ADC?

Comment: The LPF before ADC is very important. Windowing and LPF after DAC are for spectral shaping and their necessity depend on the application.

Comment: Also, these analog LPF has cut-off frequency fs/2. while Windowing is different from that?